# Algorithm Recursive Formula Calculation

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, recurrence

I have the following recursion:

```
T(n) = T(2*n / 3) + T(n / 3) + O(n log n)
```

I need to know the exact equation, I know Master theorem won't help me.

Please tell me how to do it in general for such recursions. I need complexity and to understand how to solve such problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think the Master Theorem won't help you? What is your exact question? In general, the Master Theorem is the correct way to determine the asymptotic run-time for most (not all) recursive calls.

Comment: Do you see that you're equation is `T(n) = T(n) + O(n logn)` which is very weird?

Comment: @pkacprzak That's not at all the case.

Comment: @NiklasB. what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @pkacprzak T(2*n / 3) + T(n / 3) != T(n)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst The Master Theorem requires that the 2n/3 and n/3 be the same.  You can convert the n/3 to 2n/3 to get an upper bound, as AbcAeffchen did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalization of the Master Theorem is the [Akra-Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).

Assuming that your O(n log n) is really Θ(n log n), we have g(x)=x log x, a<sub>i</sub>=1 for i=1 and i=2, b<sub>1</sub>=2/3 and b<sub>2</sub>=1/3.  Then b<sub>1</sub><sup>p</sup>+b<sub>2</sub><sup>p</sup>=1 when p=1, g(u)/u<sup>p+1</sup>=(log u)/u has integral (log²u)/2, and T(x) is Θ(x log²x).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simplification to get an upper bound.

**1. Way:**

```
T(n) = T(2/3 ⋅ n) + T(1/3 ⋅ n) + O(n log n)
     ≤ T(2/3 ⋅ n) + T(2/3 ⋅ n) + O(n log n)
     = 2 T(2/3 ⋅ n) + O(n log n)
```

Now you can use the master theorem. This should give you `O( n1.7095 )`. Due to we  have a `≤`, we do have `O` instead of `Θ`.

**2. Way:**
You can 'count' the nodes in the calling-tree, which is a binary tree in your case. This tree has maximum depth `log3/2(n)`, so it has less than `2O(log n) = O(n)` nodes. For each node there comes a `O(n log n)`, so you get `O(n) ⋅ O(n log n) = O(n² log n)` in total.

Sure, this is very unexact. We can do better if we split the tree up into two parts:

1. The upper part above depth of `1/2 ⋅ log n`: `O(21/2 ⋅ log n ) = O( sqrt(n) )` nodes.
   This nodes have a weight of `O(n log n)`.
2. The lower part below depth of `1/2 ⋅ log n`: `O(2log n - sqrt(n) ) = O(n)` nodes.
   This nodes have a weight of `O(sqrt(n) log n)`

In total you get: `T(n) = O(sqrt(n)) ⋅ O(n log n) + O(n) ⋅ O(sqrt(n) log n) = O(n1.5 log n)`.

I hope this helps.

EDIT: `O(n1.5 log n) ⊂ O(n1.7095)`.

EDIT: You can write `O(n1.5 log n)` as `O(n⋅sqrt(n)⋅log n)`. As @Teepeemm showed, the exact complexity is `Θ(n log²(n))`, which improves the upper bound I showed by replacing the factor `sqrt(n)` by `log(n)`.

Comment: Replacing T (2/3 n) + T (n/3) with T (2/3 n) + T (2/3 n) totally changes the result. T (n) = c * n * log^2 n matches the recursion formula just fine.

Comment: Sure, both results are only upper bounds, but you can get them without any heavy theory but master theorem